# How to select multiple rows in UITableView in edit mode?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multipleselection

I want to ask, how can I forward to edit mode, where I can to select multiple rows, as in Messages app, when you click on top right button "Select", when you can choose multiple messages by tapping on circles.

Like this:

[image]

I searched a lot, really, but couldn't find anything. Can anyone help me? Some advices

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Set

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Screenshot

[image]

Demo code

```
class TableviewController:UITableViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
}
```

Comment: How to make the first two cell selected by default? I tried "cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)" but not working.

Comment: This works for me "tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)"

Comment: how to get selected cells?

Comment: Can you please let me know why it will not work for custom UITableviewCell?

Comment: Can you please some one guide me how can I achieve select all and deselect all during the editing

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Storyboards do this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableArray *selected;
```

> decleare it in you viewcontroller.h file..

```
selected =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<[YOUR_ARRAY count]; i++) // Number of Rows count
        {
            [selected addObject:@"NO"];
        }
```

> add same number of "NO" in selected array using above code for that you had to replace YOUR_ARRAY with your data array that you show in table.

```
    if(![[selected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"NO"])
{

    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

}

else
{
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

> put above code in your -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];


if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [selected replaceObjectAtIndex:path.row withObject:@"YES"];
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [selected replaceObjectAtIndex:path.row withObject:@"NO"];
}
```

}

also put this to work correctly..