# allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing not working with Custom UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multipleselection

Referance [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33970936/10150796) that I have used

**Here is my code**

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
}
```

> It was Work fine for the default `UITableViewCell`. But if I have do the same thing with Custom `UITableViewCell` then **selection is not worling**

**Code with Custom Cell**

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell", for: indexPath) as! ProductTblCell
        cell.lblProductTitle?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
}
```

**ProductTblCell Calss**

```
class ProductTblCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblProductTitle: UILabel!
}
```

Can you please someone tell me what's going Wrong? Thanks in advance

**Output**

[image]

Comment: can you paste the code for `ProductTblCell` ?

Comment: @Olympiloutre It contains only a single Label I have updated it in Question you can see that as well.

Comment: Can you confirm that **didSelectRowAt** delegate is being triggered when you tap on a cell?

Comment: @ErsTar Yes It's Calling

Comment: @ErsTar Everything is fine just selection not working for custom cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was, as tends to be the case, my mistake

After searching a lot I realized the issue.

The problem was mostly we all set the cell's `selectionStyle` property to `.none` from Storyboard or programmatically to remove the background color of the cell during the selection.

> Keep in mind that if you want to use the default **selection** or
> **multiple selections** feature during the editing must you need to follow this

**Set the Selection Style from Storyboard**

[image]

**You can also Set in table views `cellForRowAt` method**

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

To remove or change the background color of the cell for the selection you need to use this override method in `UITableViewCell`

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    self.backgroundColor = selected ? .gray : .white
}
```